# Error: Your listing cannot contain javascript (".cookie", "cookie(", "replace(", IFRAME, META, or includes), cookies or base href

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I was trying to make a listing on ebay that contains JavaScript.

> Your listing cannot contain javascript (".cookie", "cookie(",
>   "replace(", IFRAME, META, or includes), cookies or base href.

The functions are working fine but it only give me errors when I use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabs a").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){

            $('.tabcontent').slideUp();
            var tabselector = $(this).attr('tabselector');
            $('#'+ tabselector).slideDown();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: um jquery is javascript.

Comment: its a JavaScript library but that was not the question.

Comment: i doubt you could use jquery.

Comment: In case anyone comes here following the same error when their listing doesn't contain any JavaScript or offending HTML tags, try removing any brackets and the word 'includes' from your description. One of these caused me quite a lot of wasted time!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need [eBay Friendly Javascript Library](http://www.jssor.com)

Reference [Embed Javascript Slideshow in eBay Listing](http://www.jssor.com/development/embed-jssor-slider-into-ebay-listing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Greg's comment it was parenthesis "(" and ")" that were causing me problems. Took those out and it went through fine